# How to Only fetch time from timestamp in laravel

Tags: laravel, datetime, time

I am working on a Laravel project. I am trying to fetch time from a timestamp. This is the code I'm using to try to accomplish this:

```
$details=DB::table('CourseListNew as cl')       
        ->select(
            'cl.Title',
            'p.Title as ParentTitle', 
            'cd.Trainer', 
            DB::raw('day(cd.StartingDate) as day'),
            DB::raw('day(cd.EndingDate) as day_end'), 
            DB::raw('(cd.StartingDate) as month'), 
            DB::raw('year(cd.StartingDate) as year'),
            DB::raw('time(cd.StartingDate) as start_time'), 
            DB::raw('time(cd.EndingDate) as end_time'), 
           'cd.StartingDate', 
           'cd.EndingDate',
           'cd.Duration',
           'cd.Type',
           'cd.Fee', 
           'cd.Venue',
            'count (s.Id) as TotalRegistartion'
        )
        ->join('CourseListNew as p','p.Id', '=', 'cl.ParentId','left')      
        ->join('CourseDetailsNew as cd','cd.CourseId', '=', 'cl.Id')        
        ->join('Student as s','s.CourseId', '=', 'cl.Id', 'left outer')     
        ->orderBy('cl.Id','DESC')
        ->get();
```

i want to get time in 12 hours format with AM/PM but not able to find any working solution. i am not using eloquent.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Or what is the result from running this code?  Providing more information when asking a question makes it more likely you'll get the answers you need.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL, you can replace the `TIME` function with `DATE_FORMAT`

```
$details=DB::table('CourseListNew as cl')       
    ->select(
        'cl.Title',
        'p.Title as ParentTitle', 
        'cd.Trainer', 
        DB::raw('day(cd.StartingDate) as day'),
        DB::raw('day(cd.EndingDate) as day_end'), 
        DB::raw('(cd.StartingDate) as month'), 
        DB::raw('year(cd.StartingDate) as year'),
        DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(cd.StartingDate, '%r') as start_time'), 
        DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(cd.EndingDate, '%r') as end_time'), 
       'cd.StartingDate', 
       'cd.EndingDate',
       'cd.Duration',
       'cd.Type',
       'cd.Fee', 
       'cd.Venue',
        'count (s.Id) as TotalRegistartion'
    )
    ->join('CourseListNew as p','p.Id', '=', 'cl.ParentId','left')      
    ->join('CourseDetailsNew as cd','cd.CourseId', '=', 'cl.Id')        
    ->join('Student as s','s.CourseId', '=', 'cl.Id', 'left outer')     
    ->orderBy('cl.Id','DESC')
    ->get();
```

The `%r` format corresponds to the 12-hour time followed by AM or PM.

For more details read the documentation on: [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

In SQL Server the equivalent method would be `FORMAT(time, N'hh:mm tt')` and you might need to refer to your own DBMS documentation for the equivalent in other flavours of SQL

For a Laravel generic solution you can of course just format the date after you've gotten the data using Carbon

Comment: Thanks for the quick help buddy, i am using sql server will try your solution and update you.

Answer (score 0):

use Mysql [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(cd.EndingDate,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') as end_time')
```

Comment: thanks i resolved ths issue using SQL Format function as suggested by @apokryfos